# Setting column to itself in an update query

Tags: sql-server

I've got a query like this,

```
UPDATE [Table.Name] SET Id=@Id, Name=@Name , ...
```

and so on.

What happens when I do this,

```
Update [Table.Name] Set Id=Id, Name=Name, ...
```

I know that practically the value doesn't change, but I'm wondering what the sql is doing on the background. Is it doing a secret select in the background and setting the value to itself or is it just ignoring that cell for the update query? Is there a performance gain for doing this instead of sending the whole row to the table.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? (things might be different in newer versions)

Comment: That is just a useless update, no more. If you do not want to change a column, then don't add it to the update statement

Comment: SQL does perform an update, it will just set the column value back to itself. However, this does become powerful if you want to modify a set of data all in the same way. If you have a table of prices, and need a 10% increase you can do: update table1 set Field1 = Field1 * 1.1, and it will iterate all rows in the table and perform the correct value calculation row by row.

Comment: the whole table will be updated with the same values, you wont see any visual changes but sql server will go through the pain of updating table any indexes if there are any and logging the full operation. really don't see any reason why one should do such an update, regardless of the version of sql server.

Comment: What do you mean "performance gain for doing this instead of sending the whole row to the table"

Comment: I wanted to learn if there is a performance difference between doing this;

Update Table Set x=1

and

Update Table Set x=x

When the value of x is already 1.

Comment: no performance difference. both statements do an update.

Comment: I feel like there should be a difference if both are doing an update to the cell.Since in the first case you are supplying the value to the query, but in the second one the SQL needs to get it from the table, unless its ignoring the SET clause all together.

Comment: it doesn't matter what you feel like :) You are asking SQL Server to perform an update, and it is obliging your request, even if the programmer is asking it to do something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the query plan. SQL server does the update.